# POSTing to non-CGI scripts?

Tags: python, python-3.x

According to the [http.server documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler) BaseHTTPRequestHandler can handle POST requests.

> class http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler(request, client_address,
>   server)¶ This class is used to handle the HTTP requests that arrive at
>   the server. By itself, it cannot respond to any actual HTTP requests;
>   it must be subclassed to handle each request method (e.g. GET or
>   **POST**). BaseHTTPRequestHandler provides a number of class and instance variables, and methods for use by subclasses.

However, down below it says:

> do_POST() This method serves the 'POST' request type, only allowed for
>   CGI scripts. Error 501, “Can only POST to CGI scripts”, is output when
>   trying to POST to a non-CGI url.

What does this part of the documentation mean? Isn't that contradicting itself or am I misunderstanding something?

EDIT: To clarify, the following method I tried seems to work, I'd just like to know what the documentation of do_POST means.

```
from os import curdir
from os.path import join as pjoin
import requests

from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

port = 18888

class StoreHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    store_path = pjoin(curdir, 'store.json')

    def do_POST(self):
        if self.path == '/store.json':
            print("Got a connection from", self.client_address)
            length = self.headers['content-length']
            data = self.rfile.read(int(length))
            print(data)                                        
            with open(self.store_path, 'w') as fh:
                fh.write(data.decode())

            self.send_response(200)
            self.end_headers()

server = HTTPServer(('localhost', port), StoreHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CGIHTTPRequestHandler IS a subclass of SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, which is a subclass of BaseHTTPRequestHandler (I found this out by looking at the source code for [SimpleHTTPServer.py](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/python/python-3/python/Lib/SimpleHTTPServer.py) and [CGIHTTPServer.py](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/python/python-3/python/Lib/CGIHTTPServer.py)). This part below:

> do_POST() This method serves the 'POST' request type, only allowed for CGI scripts. Error 501, “Can only POST to CGI scripts”, is output when trying to POST to a non-CGI url.

Refers to CGIHTTPRequestHandler, not BaseHTTPRequestHandler! See:

- [http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler)
- [CGIHTTPRequestHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler)

Answer (score 0):

`do_POST()` as documented is a method of `CGIHTTPRequestHandler`. Its default behavior does not affect `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` in any way.